# Import a value from a common source to multiple values.yml in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm in a situation where I have multiple `values-*.yml` files that are intended to configure multiple instances of an app, and all of them configure an env variable with the version of a plugin in this way:

```
# values-myapp1.yaml
env:
  - name: PLUGIN_VERSION
    value: 0.0.0
  - ...
```

```
# values-myapp2.yaml
env:
  - name: PLUGIN_VERSION
    value: 0.0.0
  - ...
```

```
# values-myapp3.yaml
env:
  - name: PLUGIN_VERSION
    value: 0.0.0
  - ...
```

...

And whenever I want to update this version I am required to change all the files. **Is there any way to centralize this in another file so that only one file change is required when updating this version?** (I'm okay with enforcing the same version for all instances).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a specific Helm setting for this value.

```yaml
# templates/deployment.yaml
env:
  - name: PLUGIN_VERSION
    value: {{ .Values.pluginVersion }}
{{ .Values.env | toYaml | indent 2 }}
```

Now you can set that specific value in a common values file

```yaml
# values-common.yaml
pluginVersion: 0.0.0
```

and pass both the per-environment settings and the common settings when you install the chart

```bash
helm install \
  -f values-common.yaml \
  -f values-dev.yaml \
  myapp1 .
```

Other paths like `helm install --set-string pluginVersion=0.0.1` will also work here, but writing a YAML (or JSON) file tends to be syntactically a little cleaner.